# unable to test rails3-bootstrap-devise-cancan with capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capybara, rspec-rails

I'm using https://github.com/RailsApps/rails3-bootstrap-devise-cancan with default test-suit setting. I have a simple spec in my spec/requests folder

```
require 'spec_helper' 

describe "Feedbacks" do
  describe "guest must be denied to visit index path" do
    before { visit feedbacks_path }
    page.should have_selector ".alert", text: "Denied" 
  end
end
```

and I run into and error "undefined local variable or method `page' for.....", trying to run this test.

I have

```
  require 'capybara/rails'
```

and

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  .....
  .......
  config.include(Capybara::DSL)
```

in my spec_healper

and in gemfile "gem "capybara", ">= 2.0.3", :group => :test"

Please help me get rid of this annoying error....